# How to have a form that saves HTML and then send it to the database (PhpMyAdmin)?

Tags: html, css, sql

I want to implement in the administration of my website that when entering the data we do not have to introduce html commands manually so that the formatting of the text is good. In the image I present if it is possible to have something as it is presented? Thank you!

Need something like this for the backoffice

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBxlj.jpg

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
    <br>
        <?php
        if(isset($errorMsg))
        {
            ?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <strong><?php echo $errorMsg; ?></strong>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
        if(isset($insertMsg)){
        ?>
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                <strong><?php echo $insertMsg; ?></strong>
            </div>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        <br>
        <h2>Nova Publicação</h2>
        <br>
        <br>
        <form method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="localizacao">Título</div>
                <br>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="txt_titulo" rows="1" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="localizacao">Texto</div>
                <br>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="txt_texto" rows="12" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <br>
            <h3>Formatação do texto</h3>
            <br>
            <img src="conteudo/formatacao.png">     
            <br>    
            <br>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="titulo">Selecionar Imagem</label>
                <input type="file" name="txt_file" class="form-control" />
                <br>
            </div>          
            <div class="form-group" align="center">
                <input type="submit"  name="btn_insert" class="btn btn-success custom-btn" value="Publicar">
                <a href="admin_recuperacao" class="btn btn-danger custom-btn">Cancelar</a>
            </div>
            <br>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's called `WYSIWYG` editor.

Comment: Your `<form>` should have a `target` attribute that points to a `.php` page (omitting it will submit the form to the current page). On this `.php` page, you'll want to use MySQLi or PDO to insert the information into a database.

Comment: How do i implement a simple WYSIWYG?

Comment: Unless you're interested in building your own, here are a few such editors: [tinyMCE](https://www.tiny.cloud/), [CKEditor](https://ckeditor.com/), [Froala](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor).